# How to add something to the table of contents which is not part of the actual document?

Tags: table-of-contents

)

So I have a \documentclass{article} thingy and lets say I have
`\subsection{Introduction}` which then appears in the table of contents as `Introduction ..... 5` But what I would like to have in the table of Content would be `Introduction (Peter).... 5`. How can I achieve this? (Of course I don't want to just write `\subsection{Introduction (Peter)}` ) I tried to mess around with `\addcontentsline` but I couldn't get it to work.. Kinda a newbie here

Thanks for any help!

Thanks!

Comment: `\subsection[Introduction (Peter)]{Introduction}` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I was hoping you wanted to add a section on page 9 3/4 which wasn't in the document at all.